# Start Apache without Virtual Host's SSL certificate file

Tags: apache, ssl, virtualhost

I have Apache 2.4.10 with name based SSL (SNI) virtual hosting.
Virtual users can use their own certificate and upload it to server.

Everything works fine until there is some error with certificate file (i.e. file is missing or with wrong name).

Problem is Apache will not start if there is some certificate problem.

Is there some solution how to start Apache with this error (i.e. all vhosts will start except that one virtual host with failure)?

This does not work:

```
<If "-f /path/to/file.crt">
    <VritualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /path/to/file.crt
    </VirtualHost>
</If>
```

...and this also does not work:

```
<VritualHost *:443>
    <If "-f /path/to/file.crt">
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /path/to/file.crt
    </If>
</VirtualHost>
```

Many thanks.

Comment: This may be better answered over at http://serverfault.com

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski  thanks, you are right, moved to [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/731642/start-apache-despite-error-in-virtual-hosts-ssl-certificate-file)